# Unable to edit file Duration in the Directus File Library UI

Tags: directus

We are using Directus 7. We noticed that when a video is uploaded via the File Library UI, the Duration isn't set (video is MP4).

It could neither be edited afterward. The only way to edit the video appears to be directly via the database. Are there some settings we are missing?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug. When adding *embeds* (eg: YouTube) this works as expected, so I think this is a bug. There's also a [bug report](https://github.com/directus/app/issues/1957) for this on GitHub (presumably by you) that should address this.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @RANGER. It is resolved in this [PR](https://github.com/directus/api/pull/1204)